# Solr .net client

Tags: .net, xml, iis, solr, client

I Was wondering how I could get the results of solr XML file and send query to it. Is it hard?
I want to do make all this in windows via IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a client for. Net - SolrNet. You can find more information at http://code.goggle.com/p/solrnet/

Answer (score 0):

Fyi - SolrNet is now over on github: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet